# Need help on HttpWebrequest

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, response.redirect

HI Guys I have the same issue and I am looking to solve it. Here is detail I have two web sites WebsiteA and WebSiteB (WebsiteB is not in my control, A type of black box for me.).

Both websites have seprate login page 
I have alist of users,password of websiteB which I stored in database. 
I want a kind of common login page. If user is login to websiteA and he want to go to websiteB, he dont have to enter the login and password information again. 
I can not touch the code of websiteB. it's alredy deployed and runing. 
In websiteB in login form they have a Userid textbox and Password textbox and and a login Button. This butoon is not a submit button. It has a click event which calls a function to validate the user. it's not a simple post. 
WebsiteB has one webpage which has different frames. After login sucessfull. The pages doesnt go to any other page it remain on the same page but load the different frame. 
According to my knowledge. I can use httpwebrequest class. But faceing the following problem.

Can not click the button. 
Response.Redirect does not work. 
It seems that WebsiteB is not storing any thing in cookies as cookies always return me a empty string

I really appriciate if anyone can help me on it. 
How Can I use response.Redirect  . As when I redirect it shows me the same login page.

Answer (score 0):

A HttpWebRequest will execute on the server of WebsiteA. Even if you execute the correct HttpWebRequest POST to WebsiteB, you won't be able to pass that session cookie to the user's browser without also immediately redirecting to WebsiteB.

There are other single-sign-on techniques you may want to investigate - the approach you have described will not work.

Comment: HI Qntmfred, Can you please explain little bit more. like How should I proced. I Will appreciate if you will guide the step that should I take in completingthis task. Once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how login works to site B I could not say for sure, but at some point, I'm sure there is a post with login information. My best guess at a solution would be try to imitate what site B does on login. Use firebug and watch what gets sent, and what is returned. You'll have to mimic this behavior.

It may be something like:
POST credentials to site B for verification, returns verification result.
If verification is good, use token from verification result to redirect to site B.

Again, without knowledge of site B, I could not say, but whatever it does, it likely does using normal http, thus you can probably duplicate it. That said, site B may forbid you from logging in by only accepting logins from certain URLs.

As for using the HttpWebRequest, I think you'll find you're better off just having a hidden form which you submit from site A.

Answer (score 0):

HI I figure out . We can create a string of XML and the converting the string into bytes and then use the normal write function of HttpWebrequest to Write the XML.